# How to Get all ids of file input in serially after click on delete button using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need one help.I have one file field and one `+` button.When user is clicking on `+` button one more file field is generating and one `-` button is creating along with 1st field field and so on.Here all ids are generating dynamically and increment accordingly.I am explaining my code below.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple_icons_57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple_icons_72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple_icons_114x114.png">
        <!--/ metas -->

        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layerslider.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullwidth/skin.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/color-blue.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/intlTelInput.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile bmargindiv1">
<label for="expcerti" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Publication/Papers Upload your publication/papers certificate.</label>
<ol id="expOl">
   <li>
     <div class="totalaligndiv">
     <div class="col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1">
         <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="expcerti" id="expcerti" />
    </div><div class="col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm " id="Expadd">+</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="Expminus" style="display:none;" >-</button>
  </div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
   </li>
</ol>                                    
 </div>
 <!--end_how_it_work_demo_div-->

        <!-- scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>

        <!--/ Superscrollorama -->


        <!--/ scripts -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
         var i=1;
         $(document).on('click','.btn-success', function () {
             $.getScript("js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js");
             $('#expOl').append("<li><div class='totalaligndiv'><div class='col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1'><input type='file' class='filestyle' data-size='lg' name='expcerti' id='expcerti"+i+"' ></div><div class='col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm ' id='Expadd'>+</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='minus' style='display:none'>-</button></div><div class='clearfix'></div></div></li>");
             //$('.filestyle').attr("id","expcerti"+i);
             $(this).css('display', 'none');
             $(this).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
              i++;
         });
         $(document).on('click','.btn-danger', function () {
             console.log('delete');
             $(this).closest("li").remove();
         });
     });
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code suppose for first field id is `expcerti` and for second field `expcerti1` and so on.if user is creating 5 field for these fields ids will be `expcerti,expcerti1,expcerti2,expcerti3,expcerti4`.I need if user is deleting any field from those 5 field ids should come serially again which i explained.Suppose user deleted 3 field the ids should again like this(`expcerti,expcerti1,expcerti2,expcerti3`).I am using Jquery for this.Please help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: @ fuyushimoya: Please read my post again.I dont have any requirement regarding delete li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to reorder the IDs of inputs where type = file, your best bet is writing a little function that renames all of the input ids each time you need to rename any of them. I think this will work for you:

```
function reorderFileInputs(){
    var counter    = 0;
    var baseString = 'expcerti';
    var fileInputs = $(document).find('input[type=file]'); //RETURNS ARRAY OF FILE INPUTS
    $.each(fileInputs, function(){
        if(counter == 0){
           this.id   = baseString;
           this.name = baseString;
        } else{
           this.id   = baseString + counter;
           this.name = baseString + counter;
        }

        counter ++;
    });
}
```

Comment: @ Robert :I need after deleting any field ids should again set serially to all remaining fields.

Comment: So you want the ids to basically auto-increment each time one of them is deleted? I'll update my answer once you confirm this is what you're after.

Comment: @ Robert : No,if any field deleted it should auto decremented.

Comment: I think your best bet will just be to create a little function that goes through and renames each id with in the correct order. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if my updated answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your code,

```
function reSequenceIDs(){
      var fileFields =  $('.filestyle');
      fileFields.toArray().forEach(function(v,i){
          $(v).attr('id', 'expcerti'+( i+ 1));
      });
    }
```

Call it from your remove code like so:

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-danger', function () {
             console.log('delete');
             $(this).closest("li").remove();
             reSequenceIDs(); // <<<----- new addition 

         });
```

Essentially what this does, is on removing the field, it takes the remaining fields and re-assigns the IDs in sequence like you described

Comment: sorry, just did.. not sure why stackoverflow messed it up first time.